# create a basket from a Pandas DataFrame - not standard transaction dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a dataset using pandas. The dataset is in the form:

**user_id**    **product_id**

> user1            product1
>
> user2            product3
>
> user1            product2

or maybe this is more clear:

> dataset=[[user1,product1],
>              [user2,product3],
>              [user1,product2]]

My goal is to use this dataset to make recommendations for products to buy. I will use Association rules - apriori algorithm for that.

As I don't have a typical dataset of transactions with more than 1 product **bought together** (in same transaction ID) and I can only work with that dataset, I thought about considering that if the user1 bought product 1 and product 2, then product 1 and product 2 are bought together.

Afterwards, I will create rules from using association rules/apriori algorithm.. but to do that I need the data to be in . the form of :

> data=[[product1,product2], [product2], [product3, product1, product2]]

So I need my dataset in the following form:

> dataset=[[user1,product1,product2],[user2,product3]]

Afterwards, I can go on further steps to apply apriori.. one-hot encoding, discovering frequent items, etc.

```
df.groupby(['user_id'])['product_id']
```

**groupby** cannot be applied because I have to apply a function .. also **pivot** function doesn't work.. and these are the only ones that I thought about when trying to do the transformation.

Comment: Perhaps explain the actual problem you are trying to solve? Making that `DataFrame`, which is a bit unclear, might not actually be part of the real problem. I'm guessing you can actually do what you want with a `groupby.apply()` without making that other `DataFrame`

Comment: Ok, I will explain

Comment: I tried to explain the problem.. I need a specific format in order to be able to use http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/apriori/ .. I have no idea how to name the question correctly as well ..

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the `DataFrame` you want to create will basically have one row for each `user_id` and a column for each different `product_id` with a 1 or 0 indicating whether that product was purchased?

Comment: yes exactly. that should be what I will use for the apriori algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUUC you can get what you want with `pd.crosstab`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['user1', 'user2', 'user1', 'user3', 'user3', 'user1', 'user2'],
                   'product_id': ['milk', 'eggs', 'milk', 'bread', 'butter', 'eggs', 'cheese']})

df1 = pd.crosstab(df.user_id, df.product_id).astype('bool').astype('int')
df1.columns.name=None
df1.index.name=None
```

df1 is now:

```
       bread  butter  cheese  eggs  milk
user1      0       0       0     1     1
user2      0       0       1     1     0
user3      1       1       0     0     0
```

---

If you need that list format, you can `groupby` + `apply(list)`.

```
df.groupby('user_id').product_id.apply(list)
#user_id
#user1    [milk, milk, eggs]
#user2        [eggs, cheese]
#user3       [bread, butter]
#Name: product_id, dtype: object
```

Or if you don't care about duplicates:

```
df.groupby('user_id').product_id.apply(set)
#user_id
#user1       {milk, eggs}
#user2     {cheese, eggs}
#user3    {bread, butter}
#Name: product_id, dtype: object
```

Comment: this answer is great - also i learnt today you can do the following `df.groupby('user_id').product_id.apply(list)`. Thank you for sharing :)

Comment: didn't know about crosstab! Thanks! with this no need to do one-hot encoding using scikit-learn for example because it delivers directly the result.

Comment: Yup! It's always good to explain the real problem at hand because sometimes there's an easier way to just get to where you want :D

Answer (score 2):

this might not be the best solution - maybe someone more experienced can provide a proper pandas solution. I managed to achieve the output you require by doing the following:

```
# set user_id as index of dataframe
df.set_index('user_id', inplace=True)

dataset=[]
for u in df.index.unique():
    data = df.loc[u]['product_id']
    data = [data] if isinstance(data, str) else data.tolist()
    dataset.append([u]+data)
```

Output:

```
[['user1', 'product1', 'product2'], ['user2', 'product3']]
```

let me know if this answers your question :)